# Blackberry table aligned

Tags: blackberry, tabular

Well, I made an application for Android (can see that in the photo). I want to do the same for Blackberry, but I'm having some trouble.

I want a title Like `GRA ENTIDAD Inc Sintomas` etc..

and then I dynamically fill all the rows with information.

This is the way I'm trying to make the rows:

```
clsHorFieldManager firstManager = new clsHorFieldManager(
                        Field.FOCUSABLE | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL, Color.WHITE);

                firstManager.add(new NullField(Field.FOCUSABLE));
                add(new SeparatorField());
                firstManager.add(new LabelField(vecCampos[2]));
                firstManager.add(new LabelField(vecCampos[3]));
                firstManager.add(new LabelField(vecCampos[4]));
                firstManager.add(new LabelField(vecCampos[5]));
                firstManager.add(new LabelField(vecCampos[6]));

                add(firstManager);
```

But I just get all fields together.. My question is, how can I make that each cell of the row can be aligned with the title? Like in picture..

[image: What i want]

Comment: I think this link may help you: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-rich-UI-layout-with-TableLayoutManager/ta-p/445299

Answer (score 0):

if you want to align the fields which you have created , best way is to create custom field and override paint and layout methods

Use setmargin and setpadding methods in constructor . even though its complicated but if you have done 1 implementation you can use multiple ways in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this -

```
clsHorFieldManager firstManager = new clsHorFieldManager(
                    Field.FOCUSABLE | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL, Color.WHITE);

            firstManager.add(new NullField(Field.FOCUSABLE));
            add(new SeparatorField());
            firstManager.add(new LabelField(vecCampos[2]));
            firstManager.add(new LabelField("  ");
            firstManager.add(new LabelField(vecCampos[3]));
            firstManager.add(new LabelField("  ");
            firstManager.add(new LabelField(vecCampos[4]));
            firstManager.add(new LabelField("  ");
            firstManager.add(new LabelField(vecCampos[5]));
            firstManager.add(new LabelField("  ");
            firstManager.add(new LabelField(vecCampos[6]));

            add(firstManager);
```